# problems with multi dimensional json arrays.... with a fiddle

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Im having a weird issue with json arrays.

Inside each array, there is another array called transactions.

It looks like so...

```
[{"account_name": "abc123",
  "transactions": [
       {"name": "1"},
       {"name": "2"}
   ]},
 {"account_name": "abc1234",
  "transactions": [
       {"name": "3"},
       {"name": "4"}
  ]}
]
```

When I loop through the array, each element is recognized **except for the transactions array**.

Here is the loop that is **supposed to send an alert foreach transactions array that is not empty**.

```
for(var i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++)
    {
        var accountLine = "<tr><td class='bold'>" + accounts[i].account_name + "</td></tr>";
        $("tbody#generalLedgerEntries").append(accountLine);
        if(accounts[i].transactions.length < 0)
        {
            alert("we have transactions!");
            for(var j = 0; j < accounts[i].transactions.length; j++)
            {
                var transLine = "<tr><td>" + accounts[i].transactions[j].type + "</td></tr>";
                $("tbody#generalLedgerEntries").append(transLine);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is a working copy of the issue on jsfiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/Ntrca/1/

Comment: I think it's just a typo here: `accounts[i].transactions.length < 0` should be `accounts[i].transactions.length > 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have your comparison operator backward to me.  Should be:

```
if(accounts[i].transactions.length > 0)
```

When I make that change in the fiddle, I get the alert about transactions.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "type" attribute of any of the stuff in your "transactions" arrays. Also, you check for the length for being **less than** zero instead of greater than.

Comment: I dummed down the data and forgot that in there.

Comment: @Peter doing a jsfiddle is definitely a cool thing, and as a question-answerer I appreciate it :-)

Comment: Yea.. sometimes is easier just to show the issue in action vs trying to run the code here in your mind...;) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

change "type" to "name" and all works as intended...